# Parentheses pairing ({}[]()<>) issue

Tags: python, parentheses, syntax-checking

I want to be able to pair up all parentheses in a string, if they aren't paired then then they get their index number and False. It seems like it is repeating some values over and over, i.e cl == pop[1]. I have tried to see where the problem is but I can't see it no matter how hard I try. So I'm asking if anyone help me to locate the error and maybe even improve my code ;)

```
def check_parentheses(string):
    pending = 0
    brackets = []
    '''Checks if parens are paired, otherwise they are bad.'''
    parenstack = collections.deque()
    for ch in string:
        if ch in lrmap:
            try:
                cl = string.index(ch, pending)
                pending = cl + 1

            except:
                cl = False

        if ch in lparens:
            parenstack.append([ch, cl])
            print parenstack

        elif ch in rparens:
            try:
                pop = parenstack.pop()

                if lrmap[pop[0]] != ch:
                    print 'wrong type of parenthesis popped from stack',\
                    pop[0], ch, pop[1], cl

                    brackets.append([pop[1], False])
                    brackets.append([cl, False])
                else:
                    brackets.append([pop[1], cl])

            except IndexError:
                print 'no opening parenthesis left in stack'
                brackets.append([cl, False])

    # if we are not out of opening parentheses, we have a mismatch
    for p in parenstack:
        brackets.append([p[1],False])
    return brackets
```

Comment: For starters, this script doesn't include all of the variables needed to run it. Luckily, I found the rest of the code online (http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=5842). Anyway, you might want to post some examples of how the function is run, what you expect as output, and what you get instead.

Comment: More info about punctuation matching [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets).

Comment: @Patrick: Note the accepted answer for the question you linked to.

Comment: I'll edit the post after I get this foot out of my mouth.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can adapt my code to a similar question:

```
def Evaluate(str):
  stack = []
  pushChars, popChars = "<({[", ">)}]"
  for c in str :
    if c in pushChars :
      stack.append(c)
    elif c in popChars :
      if not len(stack) :
        return False
      else :
        stackTop = stack.pop()
        balancingBracket = pushChars[popChars.index(c)]
        if stackTop != balancingBracket :
          return False
    else :
      return False
  return not len(stack)
```

Comment: I think it will be better if you will remove last "else :return False" cause it confusing and took time to understand that this part need to be removed if string contains not only parentheses

Answer (score 9):

```
iparens = iter('(){}[]<>')
parens = dict(zip(iparens, iparens))
closing = parens.values()

def balanced(astr):
    stack = []
    for c in astr:
        d = parens.get(c, None)
        if d:
            stack.append(d)
        elif c in closing:
            if not stack or c != stack.pop():
                return False
    return not stack
```

Example:

```
>>> balanced('[1<2>(3)]')
True
>>> balanced('[1<2(>3)]')
False
```

Comment: @pilmuncher, I like your approach to the problem. I was little confused with the statement 'return not stack'. But got that clarified from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839849/python-return-not-statement-in-subprocess-returncode

Comment: @ASANT Maybe `return not bool(stack)` would be clearer?

Comment: @pilmuncher: I like the user of `iter()` to alternate between characters in the string. Also, the use of a `dict` is the obviously better approach.

Comment: Great answer.  The only thing is that `balanced('""')` is not handled, the corresponding opening and closing chars must not be equal.

Answer (score 4):

```
BRACES = { '(': ')', '[': ']', '{': '}' }

def group_check(s):
    stack = []
    for b in s:
        c = BRACES.get(b)
        if c:
            stack.append(c)
        elif not stack or stack.pop() != b:
            return False
    return not stack
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks hughdbrown your code was a breeze to get working and it's really short! You've just saved me a headache :D

converted it to pep8 if thats ok :)

**Edit**

- Added support for comments and strings, it will not match inside them.
- Added support for easy language brace checking, modify the charset dict.
- Correctly paires up, i.e right to left

### HTML

```
charset = dict(opening='{[(<',\
    closing='}])>',\
    string = ('"', "'"),\
    comment=(('<!--', '-->')))
```

### Python

```
charset = dict(opening='{[(<',\
    closing='}])>',\
    string = ('"', "'"),\
    comment=(("'''", "'''"), ('"""', '"""'), ('#', '\n')))
```

### C++

```
charset = dict(opening='{[(<',\
    closing='}])>',\
    string = ('"', "'"),\
    comment=(('/*', '*/'), ('//', '\n')))
```

**you get the point?** :)

```
charset = dict(opening='{[(<',\
    closing='}])>',\
    string = ('"', "'"),\
    comment=(('<!--', '-->'), ('"""', '"""'), ('#', '\n')))

allowed = ''.join([x[0][0] + x[1][0] for x in charset['comment']])
allowed += ''.join(charset['string'])
allowed += charset['opening']
allowed += charset['closing']

def brace_check(text):
    o = []
    c = []
    notr = []
    found = []
    busy = False
    last_pos = None
    for i in xrange(len(text)):
        ch = text[i]
        if not busy:
            cont = True
            for comment in charset['comment']:
                if ch == comment[0][0]:
                    como = text[i:len(comment[0])]
                    if como == comment[0]:
                        busy = comment[1]
                        if ch in charset['opening']:
                            last_pos = i
                        cont = False
                        break
            if cont:
                if ch in charset['string']:
                    busy = ch
                elif ch in charset['opening']:
                    o.append((ch, i))
                elif  ch in charset['closing']:
                    c.append((ch, i))
        else:
            if ch == busy[0]:
                if len(busy) == 1:
                    comc = ch
                else:
                    comc = text[i:i + len(busy)]
                if comc == busy:
                    if last_pos is not None:
                        if busy[-1] in charset['closing']:
                            found.append((last_pos, i))
                        last_pos = None
                        text = text[:i] + '\n' * len(comc) +\
                            text[i + len(comc):]
                    busy = not busy
            elif busy in charset['string']:
                if ch == '\n':
                    busy = not busy
    for t, e in reversed(o):
        try:
            n = next((b, v) for b, v in c\
                if b == charset['closing'][\
                    charset['opening'].find(t)] and v > e)
            c.remove(n)
            n = n[1]
            if found != []:
                if e < found[-1][0] and n > found[-1][0] and n < found[-1][1]\
                or e < found[-1][1] and n > found[-1][1] and e > found[-1][0]:
                    found.append((n, False))
                    n = False
        except StopIteration:
            n = False
        found.append((e, n))
    for t, e in c:
        found.append((e, False))
    return found
```

Comment: The code is really complicated and hard to read. I suggest posting it on codereview.stackexchange.com for some advice on how to clean it up.

Comment: I agree with @Winston; start by removing most of the blank lines.

Comment: hmm, I think it's easier to read formatted this way.
It's funny that everyone think different, will update it shortly,
finding out some more bugs :)

Answer (score 0):

An understandable solution in Python 3:

```
def check_balanced_string(str):
  stack = []
  dicc = {'(': ')', '[': ']', '{': '}'}
  for char in str:
    if char in dicc.keys():  # opening char
      stack.append(char)
    elif char in dicc.values():  # closing char
      if dicc[stack[-1]] == char:  # check if closing char corresponds to last opening char
        stack.pop()
      else:
        return False
  return not len(stack)  # returns True when len == 0

eq = '{1+[3*5+(2+1)]}'
print(check_balanced_string(eq))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def matched(s):
stack=[]
open,close="(",")" 
for i in s:
    if i in open:
        stack.append(i)
    if i in close:
        if len(stack)==0:
            return(False)
        else:   
            stack.pop()
if len(stack):
    return(False)
else:
    return(True)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will display the missing parentheses and the no of times missing in the given string.

```
from collections import Counter

def find_missing(str):
    stack1 = []
    stack2 = []
    result = []
    res_dict = {}
    open_set = '<[{('
    closed_set = '>]})'
    a = list(str)
    for i in a:
        if i in open_set:
            stack1.append(i)
        elif i in closed_set:
            stack2.append(i)
    dict1 = Counter(stack1)
    dict2 = Counter(stack2)
    print(dict1)
    print(dict2)
    for i in open_set:
        if dict1[i] > dict2[closed_set[open_set.index(i)]]:
            res_dict[closed_set[open_set.index(i)]] = dict1[i] - dict2[closed_set[open_set.index(i)]]
            result.append(closed_set[open_set.index(i)])
    for i in closed_set:
        if dict2[i] > dict1[open_set[closed_set.index(i)]]:
            res_dict[open_set[closed_set.index(i)]] = dict2[i] - dict1[open_set[closed_set.index(i)]]
            result.append(open_set[closed_set.index(i)])
    return res_dict
    # return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    str1 = '{This ((()bracket {[function]} <<going> crazy}'
    x = find_missing(str1)
    if len(x) > 0:
        print("Imbalanced")
        print(x)
    else:
        print("Balanced")
```

Answer (score 0):

First we will scan the string from left to right, and every time we see an opening parenthesis we push it to a stack, because we want the last opening parenthesis to be closed first. (Remember the FILO structure of a stack!)
Then, when we see a closing parenthesis we check whether the last opened one is the corresponding closing match, by popping an element from the stack. If it’s a valid match, then we proceed forward, if not return false.
Code:
https://gist.github.com/i143code/51962bfb1bd5925f75007d4dcbcf7f55

Answer (score 0):

I needed something for a recent project and figured I could build on the OP's solution a bit. It allows for comment patterns, quotes and brackets to be checked, whilst ignoring the surrounding text. I've purposefully made it more generic than it needs to be so that others can take what they want and cut out what they don't.

```
"""
This module is for testing bracket pairings within a given string
Tested with Python 3.5.4
>>> regexp = getRegexFromList(opening + closing)
>>> print(regexp)
(\\<\\-\\-|\\-\\-\\>|\\/\\*|\\/\\/|\\*\\/|\\#|\\"|\\'|\\(|\\[|\\{|\\<|\\\n|\\\n|\\"|\\'|\\)|\\]|\\}|\\>)
>>> test_string = 'l<--([0])-->1/*{<2>}*/3//<--4 &-->\\n5#"6"\\n7"/*(8)*/"9\'"10"\'11({12\ta})13[<14>]'
>>> patterns = re.findall(regexp, test_string)
>>> print(patterns)
['<--', '(', '[', ']', ')', '-->', '/*', '{', '<', '>', '}', '*/', '//', '<--', '-->', '\\n', '#', '"', '"', '\\n', '"', '/*', '(', ')', '*/', '"', '(', '{', '}', ')', '[', '<', '>', ']']
>>> doBracketsMatch(patterns)
True
>>> doBracketsMatch(['"', ')', '"', '[', ']', '\\''])
False
"""


# Dependencies
import re


# Global Variables
# Provide opening and closing patterns, along with their priorities & whether a priority is nestable
opening =  ['<--', '/*', '//',  '#', '"', '\'', '(', '[', '{', '<']
closing =  ['-->', '*/', '\n', '\n', '"', '\'', ')', ']', '}', '>']
priority = [    1,    1,    1,    1,   1,    1,   0,   0,   0,   0]
nestable = {0: True, 1: False}
bracket_pairs = dict(zip(opening + closing, \
                         [[(closing + opening)[i], (priority + priority)[i]] \
                          for i in range(0, opening.__len__() * 2)]))


def getRegexFromList(listOfPatterns):
    """
    Generate the search term for the regular expression
    :param listOfPatterns:
    :return:
    >>> getRegexFromList(['"', '<--', '##', 'test'])
    '(\\\\t\\\\e\\\\s\\\\t|\\\\<\\\\-\\\\-|\\\\#\\\\#|\\\\")'
    """
    # Longer patterns first to prevent false negatives
    search_terms = sorted(listOfPatterns, key=len, reverse=True)
    regex = ""
    for term in search_terms:
        for char in str(term):
            regex = regex + '\\' + char  # Search for all characters literally
        regex = regex + '|'  # Search pattern = (a|b|c)
    return '(' + regex[:-1] + ')'  # Remove excess '|' and add brackets


def doBracketsMatch(list_of_brackets):
    """
    Determine if brackets match up
    :param list_of_brackets:
    :return:
    """
    stack = []
    for bracket in list_of_brackets:
        # Check empty stack conditions
        if stack.__len__() is 0:
            # Check for openings first to catch quotes
            if bracket in opening:
                stack.append(bracket)
            elif bracket in closing:
                return False
            else:
                continue
        # Check for a matching bracket
        elif bracket == bracket_pairs[stack[-1]][0]:
            stack.pop()
        # Ignore cases:
        #  - False positives
        #  - Lower priority brackets
        #  - Equal priority brackets if nesting is not allowed
        elif bracket not in bracket_pairs or \
                bracket_pairs[bracket][1] < bracket_pairs[stack[-1]][1] or \
                (bracket_pairs[bracket][1] == bracket_pairs[stack[-1]][1] and \
                    not nestable[bracket_pairs[bracket][1]]):
            continue
        # New open bracket
        elif bracket in opening:
            stack.append(bracket)
        # Otherwise, unpaired close bracket
        else:
            return False
    # If stack isn't empty, then there is an unpaired open bracket
    return not bool(stack)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```