# Python 'return not' statement in subprocess returncode

Tags: python, return, subprocess, popen, return-code

I just came across a very strange line of code in Python:

```
....
self.myReturnCode = externalProcessPopen.returncode
....
....
return not self.myReturnCode
....
```

What exactly `return not` stands for? I am aware that the returncode of a Popen process is None while it's still running and a random number once it completes and exits successfully. But what exactly is the author of the code trying to achieve here?

It might also be worth noting that the same author later on checks the return code like this:

```
if not testClass.testFunction():
    logger.error('Failed to execute Function')
    ....
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`not` is a [boolean operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) that returns the boolean inverse of the value. `return` returns the result of that operator. In other words, the expression should be read as `return (not self.myReturnCode)`. Quoting the documentation:

> The operator `not` yields `True` if its argument is false, `False` otherwise.

If `self.myReturnCode` is a true value, `not self.myReturnCode` is `False`, and vice versa. Note that `self.myReturnCode` can be any Python value, but `not` *always* returns a boolean value, either `True` or `False`.

If `externalProcessPopen.returncode` is the return code of an external process, then it'll be a positive integer if the process exited with an error, `0` if it exited successfully. This is called the [process exit status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status); what non-zero values are returned depends entirely on the process. `not 0` is then `True`, `not 1` (or a higher integer value) gives you `False`.

If it is `None`, then `True` (`not None` is `True`) would be returned as well, but a `subprocess.Popen()` return code is *only* `None` if the process has not yet exited.

Comment: It seems you are suggesting that 0 is not a true value (why?) while 1 or higher integer values are true values. This begs the question what is the definition of a 'true value'?

Comment: @Konos5: don't confuse process exit status convention with Python booleans. The `not` translates one convention to another; `0` means success for process, translated to `True` here.

Comment: Yes, I get that. 0 is success for the process but it seems that for Python is not a true value - that's why we use not. My question is why is 0 not considered a true value in the first place..

Comment: Numeric 0, empty containers and empty strings are all considered false in Python. This makes for very readable code in many situations. Why do you feel `0` should be true instead?

Comment: And historically, booleans in Python are relatively new. In C, `0` is false as well, and Python used integers instead of booleans for a long time. Today, `bool` is a subclass of `int` and `True == 1` and `False == 0` are both true.

Comment: I was a bit confused but now totally covered. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
return not self.myReturnCode
```

is to be interpreted as:

```
return (not self.myReturnCode)
```

What it is doing in your code is simply this:

- If the returncode is `0` then return `True`
- If the returncode is not `0` then return `False`.

Answer (score 3):

```
return not self.myReturnCode
```

is equivalent to:

```
return False if self.myReturnCode else True
```

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't be a random number, it's the return code of the external process, where zero indicates success and a non-zero number indicates failure.

Hence returning `not self.myReturnCode` means it returns `True` when the process was successful and `False` when the process indicated failure.